# Is there somewhere in the Belize City airport to buy local coffee?

Tags: belize

As an annoying coffee nerd, I am wondering if there is somewhere in the Belize City airport to buy roasted, local coffee?

Answer (score 2):

Two shops in the international terminal sell (the same) local coffee, one of the duty-free shops and the "convenience store."

In December 2022, they sold 12 oz bags for 10 USD.